# Sendgrid NodeJS recieved previous mail already sent

Tags: firebase, next.js, twilio, sendgrid, vercel

Using: NextJS, Firebase (Auth, DB, etc...), Hosted on Vercel, OVH Domains, (Using next to for the backend (node))

Basically, went I send an email with Sendgrid library or with the API v3 directly, my mail got strange behavior.

When I send a mail to any address, I don't recieve de mail at all, I need to make multiple time THE SAME request to get the answer of the first, isn't that weird at all?

Like I send "1" to "joe@example.com", joe recieve nothing, I make the same request with "2", joe recieve nothing, then I make another "3", then finnally joe has recieved the first mail.

Then when I send other mail, I send the "4" I will recieve the "2", etc....
I feel like there is a Queue within my mail.
At first, if I'm not wrong the mail was always gapped by 1 when I used the library below. Then I moved to the API directly thinking it was a library issue.

Using the library

```
import { getAuth } from 'firebase-admin/auth'
import { supportConfig, websiteConfig, sendgridConfig } from 'src/config'
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail'
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

/**
 * @name verifyEmail
 * @description Send email verify link to user email
 * @param {string} email
 * @param {any} actionCodeSettings
 * @returns Promise<Void>
 */

export default async function verifyEmail(
  email: string,
  actionCodeSettings: any
): Promise<void> {
  const pathTemplate = path.join(
    process.cwd(),
    'src/api/lib/user/actionCode/emailTemplate/verifyEmail.html'
  )
  return await getAuth()
    .generateEmailVerificationLink(email as string)
    .then(async (link) => {
      sgMail.setApiKey(sendgridConfig.apiKey as string)
      fs.readFile(pathTemplate, 'utf8', async function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          throw err
        }
        const msg = {
          to: [email, supportConfig.email as string],
          from: supportConfig.email as string,
          subject: "Email verification",
          text: 'Please click on the link',
          html: data.replace('{{link}}', link),
        }
        await sgMail
        .send(msg)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Email sent!')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
          throw error
        })
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      throw error
    })
}
```

Using the api directly

```
        const message = {
          personalizations: [
            {
              to: [
                {
                  email: email,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
          from: {
            email: 'support@nerap.fr',
            name: 'Support',
          },
          replyTo: {
            email: 'support@nerap.fr',
            name: 'Support',
          },
          subject: 'Email verification',
          content: [
            {
              type: 'text/html',
              value: data.replace('{{link}}', link),
            },
          ],
        }
        await axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send',
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${sendgridConfig.apiKey}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          data: message,
        })
```

Nothing fancy, it's like the template that Sendgrid give us.
Honestly I'm lost I don't have any lead to fix it.

Here come the crazy part, IT'S PERFECTLY WORKING ON LOCAL.

So I think my conclusion is this.
Vercel hosting might be limited or restricted by Sengrid this is the only rationnal way.
Like, I don't know, I took the priced version thinking it was a trick to force people to use the pay version.
I'm open to any suggestion thanks !

Comment: If you send the email and then wait without sending other emails, does it arrive? Emails can take time to get across the internet, I suspect that when you send the 3rd email and receive the first one, that's just how long it took to arrive.

Comment: No that's the thing, it's really the moment I send, I recieve it it's pretty fast, but, it's the previous one, not the one intended.
At first I thought it was the issue but it's not I'm 100% on it.

Comment: Are you sending the email in a Serverless function but returning before the asynchronous request is finished? Can you share the code context in which you are sending the emails?

Comment: Yes in fact, it's "vercel" serveless function, BUT, I'm waiting de promise to be resolve.
After many test I am always 1 email late, it's so fustrating, I can wait 2 min or 30 min, the next will be sent right after a new one is called, then the new will be stuck until another request his made.

Comment: If I send "hello' to "joe@gmail.com", he will not recieve it
Then, if I send "hello" to "lila@gmail.com", she will not recieve it, BUT, "joe@gmail.com" will recieve "hello" from the first mail.
Then, if I send "hello" to "Johnny@gmail.com", THEN "lila@gmail.com" will recieve the email that I sent previously! And so on....
I am alaways 1 email short or delay by something and I've no clue why.

Comment: My suspicion is still that there is an async call that is happening beyond the life of the function. Can you share the code context around where you call on the API to send the email?

Comment: I updated the full code above but it's an async function so no fancy context at all (Vercel serverless function)

I call the function like this in another serveless function but nothing to worry about
await verifyEmail(email as string, actionCodeSettings)

Comment: I note you added an edit to my answer, have you tried out the solution and did it work? Does the description make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing the code, it highlighted an asynchronous piece of code that was allowing your function to complete before it ran. On platforms like Vercel, when a function completes, the event loop is effectively suspended, but continues when the function runs again. In this case your code was not completing before the function ended, which is why later emails would trigger the email to be sent.

The asynchronous code that escaped was the use of `fs.readFile` within a promise. Calling on `fs.readFile` started the work to read the email template from the filesystem asynchronously, and would call the callback when done, which would then send the email. However, the execution of the function would continue and complete before that finished. Since you are using promises for everything else in this code, I'd recommend using `fs/promises` (with the line `import { promises as fs } from 'fs'`) so that you can treat `fs.readFile` like the rest of your code. I rewrote your function below using the promise version, and hopefully this will work.

```js
import { getAuth } from 'firebase-admin/auth'
import { supportConfig, websiteConfig, sendgridConfig } from 'src/config'
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail'
import path from 'path'
import { promises as fs } from 'fs'

/**
 * @name verifyEmail
 * @description Send email verify link to user email
 * @param {string} email
 * @param {any} actionCodeSettings
 * @returns Promise<Void>
 */

export default async function verifyEmail(
  email: string,
  actionCodeSettings: any
): Promise<void> {
  const pathTemplate = path.join(
    process.cwd(),
    'src/api/lib/user/actionCode/emailTemplate/verifyEmail.html'
  )
  return await getAuth()
    .generateEmailVerificationLink(email as string)
    .then(async (link) => {
      sgMail.setApiKey(sendgridConfig.apiKey as string)
      try {
        const data = await fs.readFile(pathTemplate, 'utf8');
        const msg = {
          to: [email, supportConfig.email as string],
          from: supportConfig.email as string,
          subject: "Email verification",
          text: 'Please click on the link',
          html: data.replace('{{link}}', link),
        }
        await sgMail
        .send(msg)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Email sent!')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
          throw error
        })
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        throw error
      }
      })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      throw error
    })
}
```

You do have a confusing mix of `then/catch` and `async/await` in your code. I'd recommend using just one style in order to simplify things. With just `async/await` your code could look like this:

```js
import { getAuth } from 'firebase-admin/auth'
import { supportConfig, websiteConfig, sendgridConfig } from 'src/config'
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail'
import path from 'path'
import { promises as fs } from 'fs'

/**
 * @name verifyEmail
 * @description Send email verify link to user email
 * @param {string} email
 * @param {any} actionCodeSettings
 * @returns Promise<Void>
 */

export default async function verifyEmail(
  email: string,
  actionCodeSettings: any
): Promise<void> {
  const pathTemplate = path.join(
    process.cwd(),
    'src/api/lib/user/actionCode/emailTemplate/verifyEmail.html'
  )
  try {
    const auth = getAuth()
    const link = await auth.generateEmailVerificationLink(email as string)
    sgMail.setApiKey(sendgridConfig.apiKey as string)
    const data = await fs.readFile(pathTemplate, 'utf8')
    const msg = {
      to: [email, supportConfig.email as string],
      from: supportConfig.email as string,
      subject: "Email verification",
      text: 'Please click on the link',
      html: data.replace('{{link}}', link),
    }
    await sgMail.send(msg)
    console.log('Email sent!')
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw error
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunatly your solution is not exactly right, in fact fs.readFile doesn't return anything, and has a callback function that will be called as soon as the buffer become available.
So there is a callback needed, but you pointed an interesting fact that serveless function can stop even if the promise is never fullfilled. And will be able to fullfilled it next time.. Really strange behavior

Comment: You may have missed that I replaced your `import fs from 'fs'` with `import { promises as fs } from 'fs'` so that `fs.readFile` returns a promise that resolves with the contents of the file. That's why the code now uses `const data = await fs.readFile(pathTemplate, "utf-8")`.